# How to get tcp/udp ports list of target application

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I know there are many commands we can use to get the open tcp and udp ports of specific application. For example, supposing we have an application whose name is APP, then we can get its port via: lsof -i | grep 'APP', or, netstat -anp | grep APP.

But can we do this via c/c++ source code on linux? Are there any way to achieve this, such as scan the contents under /proc/app/ or using any system API?

Comment: one possible solution is using popen to run the command and read the result

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/system/core/toolbox/netstat.c) will give you list of ports being used, and [netstat source code](http://cvs.berlios.de/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/net-tools/net-tools/netstat.c) from net-tools suite may be of help to you